# How to negate some users while retrieving users from Google Apps

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I can apply the filter to get the specific users while retrieving all the users based on givenName, familyName and email attributes. But the requirement is to apply the filter such that it excludes some users while retrieving all the users e.g i don't want users which has givenName=admin*. I know that we can do post processing locally once all the users has been returned by Google API but it may have performance impact to exclude the unwanted users locally.

Is there any way to pass the filter to google APIs so that it return the all the users excluding the unwanted users?

Comment: What do you mean with "negate"?

Comment: Hi
 negate means exclude ,  For example https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users" this will give the list of users,but i want to list the user but not those users which start with givenName; 'A*'

Comment: Hi Allner,
"Negate" means exclude , For example googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users" API gives the list of users,but i want to list the user but not those users which start with givenName; 'A*'.